# How to credit other authors in an open source project

Tags: open-source, licensing

I have a pet project that I am planning to release as open source at some point in the not-too-distant future. A couple of the files use or are mostly code that was taken from a project released under the New BSD License. While I have changed it to fit my needs and added some small stuff, the algorithm and the functionality is basically exactly the same.

I want to make sure that the author of the code gets credit and that the license is not broken, but I also want to make the reader aware that this is not the code as it was orignally released.

How should I approach this? Should I isolate the code as much as possible and just retain the original license? Maybe put all the files that contain foreign code in their own folder and add a readme explaining what has been added/removed?

There must have been tons of projects using other open source code. What is the standard approach to this?

Comment: I have a similar question. In a project of my own, I will occasionally receive patches - some of which are non-trivial. I always wrestle with how much/little to acknowledge the people who submit them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the files you use have (had) a header stating their origin, keep them. If they don't have, add one. You could also add an `AUTHORS` file to your project where you list all authors and all projects you took code from. If the code you use has a different license, it might also be good to add an extra license file for that. For instance, if you use source code of the *fooBar* project, add a file `COPYING.fooBar` to your project that contains the license of fooBar.